# Use Automator to email a word doc

Tags: email, ms-word, applescript, automator

I do work over a few computers and use my email address to keep an extra save copy of my files. I'd like to have an Automator service for Microsoft Word that sends an email to myself with the current word doc as an attachment and the title as the subject. If I could have a macro in Word that did the same thing that would also be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either run this as an AppleScript by itself or insert the AppleScript in your Automator workflow.

```
    tell application "Microsoft Word"
    try
        set theTitle to name of front document
    end try
    send mail front document
end tell

tell application "Mail"
    activate
    tell its outgoing message 1
        set subject to theTitle
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: will this have the subject of the email as the document name?

Comment: what about making it universal in all document editing applications?